# /%post_name%/ or /%postname%/ in Permalinks?

Tags: permalinks, options

In Settings-->Permalinks is there any difference between:

checking Custom Structure and using:

/%post_name%/

or

/%postname%/

Are they both correct? Will they both work?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: have you read: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/%postname%/` is the correct one and if you are asking be cause it says post_name in the codex then its just to show that you will get the actual post name.

Comment: Hi Bainternet, Thank you for for your help. I appreciate the clarification. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

I just read a really good and informative article suggesting you should never use `/%postname%/` I've used that since the beginning for SEO reasons. I've heard arguments throughout the years suggesting this was a bad idea. After reading the article I'm linking to I immediately switched all sites I'm associated with to `/%post_id%/%postname%/`
The article suggests that using the old way can cause a large increase DB queries.

There are some pretty respected names in this discussion, all are in agreement. It sounds like it might be resolved with V 3.3, but I've decided not to take a chance. Here is the link:
[Digging Into WordPress Article](http://digwp.com/2011/06/dont-use-postname/?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20DiggingIntoWordpress%20%28Digging%20Into%20WordPress%29)

Comment: This will definitely be different in 3.3. It's a blessed task. See http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16687

Comment: @OTTO:      Thanks for confirming that there will be a change in the next official release. Maybe switching "immediately" was a knee jerk reaction. I was trying to be pro-active, but may have been "reactive". Either way it will be good to have more options. It's nice to see WordPress grow and the great community that follows.